# Connection is open, but I get "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

Tags: sql, connection

I'm getting the dreaded "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed." error, even though the connection is open ( see image). Here's my code. Where am I going wrong? I'm getting the error at the *queryInsertSong.ExecuteNonQuery();* call.

```
        connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionManager.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string insertSong = "Insert into Songs (SongTitle, Artist, Genre, Album, Year, Length, FullPath) " +
                "VALUES (@SongTitle, @Artist, @Genre, @Album, @Year, @Length, @FullPath)";
            using (SqlCommand queryInsertSong = new SqlCommand(insertSong, conn))
            {
                queryInsertSong.Connection = connectionManager.DBConnection;
                queryInsertSong.Parameters.Add("@SongTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = song.SongTitle;
                queryInsertSong.Parameters.Add("@Artist", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = song.Artist;
                queryInsertSong.Parameters.Add("@Genre", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = song.Genre;
                queryInsertSong.Parameters.Add("@Album", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = song.Album;
                queryInsertSong.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = song.Year;
                queryInsertSong.Parameters.Add("@Length", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = song.Length;
                queryInsertSong.Parameters.Add("@FullPath", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = song.FullPath;

                queryInsertSong.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

[image: Connection is open]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already you have initialized a sqlCommand with conn`new SqlCommand(insertSong, conn)`. The below line will replace the existing connection and assign new one and it will be in closed state. So, remove the below line.

```
queryInsertSong.Connection = connectionManager.DBConnection;
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use this if condition before execute query

```
if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
conn.Close();
conn.Open();
}
```

And no need this line

```
 queryInsertSong.Connection = connectionManager.DBConnection;
```